# How can I pass a unique ID in a url to other pages on my site?

Tags: php

Client wants to try some retargeting with banner ads (using Google adwords) and is having us keep the lead sources seperate. Lead source ID is submitted with the form the user will fill out. I want to create a unique id for the retargeting banners like so: http://www.mysite.com/index.php/?id=12345 and then pass that id on to other pages so when they eventually end up on the form and submit it, I can take that id and submit it with the form to the database to track the lead source (which will be associated with the id).

How can I do this?

Hopefully that is not confusing! I am new to PHP and things like this in general, so any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Here is the code that I am using.

index.php

```
<?php session_start();

include("includes/dynamicVars.php");

if (isset($_GET['id']))
{ 
   $_SESSION['leadID'] = 'MICROSITE_RETARGET_CROSS';
   $siteCode = $_SESSION['leadID'];
   echo "Retarget ID set!";
}
else 
{ echo "Default PPC ID set!";}

?>
```

$siteCode is defined as 'MICROSITE_PPC_CROSS' by default in dynamicVars.php

Then Page2.php

```
<?php session_start(); 
    include("includes/dynamicVars.php");
    echo $siteCode;
?>
```

And I still get the default $siteCode, instead of the new one that is set on index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, when you go back to the index.php page, it no longer has the ID in the URL, which means the if statement goes straight to Default PPC. So what you should do is create another SESSION or you could use a COOKIE that let's you know the visitor is the same person. Example:

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['visitor'])){

  // do nothing 
     }else{

// create the SESSION for leadID
        if (isset($_GET['id']))
        { 
           $_SESSION['leadID'] = 'MICROSITE_RETARGET_CROSS';

           echo "Retarget ID set!";
        }
        else 
        { echo "Default PPC ID set!";}

        }

    // write session for new visitor
        $_SESSION['visitor'] = "currentvisitor";

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to take the ID and  put it in a $_SESSION['leadID'];
If you want to use it with JavaScript, you should put it in a cookie.

Comment: Okay, so I am not quite sure how to do this (sorry) but I did do this, and I can't get the variable to pass to different pages:

index.php

`code` 

<?php session_start();

include("includes/dynamicVars.php");

if (isset($_GET['id']))
 { 
 $_SESSION['leadID'] = 'MICROSITE_RETARGET_CROSS';
 $siteCode = $_SESSION['leadID'];
 echo "retarget is set!";
 }
else 
 { echo "default ppc is set!";}


?>

`code`

Then on page2.php

`code`

echo $siteCode;

`code`

And I get the default $siteCode (which is MICROSITE_PPC_CROSS). :( What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Updated my question with some code, that might help clarify what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

ok I took a look at this. On the second page, instead of "echo $siteCode", do "echo $_SESSION['leadID']". and then you can set "$siteCode = $_SESSION['leadID']" on this page.

I think $siteCode is not global unless you put it in the include file and have it appear everywhere. but Using Session is known as a super global array.

Comment: Okay, I did this instead and it seems to be working EXCEPT if I click on the index.php again. Then it seems to be resetting - I get the "Default PPC ID set!" message.